# How to pass a uiview to a component by props in react native?

Tags: react-native

```
<RCTNavigatorItem
      titleView={route.titleView}
... />
```

I'm trying the like, but it's not working.

PS:
1. RCTNavigatorItem is a component with native behind.
2. route.titleView is a react component

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error. Just the titleView stays nil.